# Incorrect attempt: Relational Division in PostgreSQL using Not Exist/Not In

Tags: sql, postgresql

Instructions: Given `film_actor` and `film` tables from the DVD Rental sample database find all movies both Sidney Crowe `(actor_id = 105)` and Salma Nolte `(actor_id = 122)` cast in together and order the result set alphabetically.

> Film Schema

```
Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
title       | character varying(255)      | not null
film_id     | smallint                    | not null
```

> Film_Actor Schema

```
Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
actor_id    | smallint                    | not null
film_id     | smallint                    | not null
last_update | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

> Actor Schema

```
Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
actor_id    | integer                     | not null 
first_name  | character varying(45)       | not null
last_name   | character varying(45)       | not null
last_update | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

> Desired Output

```
title
-------------
Film Title 1
Film Title 2
...
```

My **incorrect** attempt:

```
select f.title
from Film F inner join 
     film_actor FA on F.film_id = FA.film_id
where not exists (select film_id from film as F 
                  where actor_id = '105') 
                    and f.film_id not in (select film_id from 
                    film as F2 where FA.actor_id = '122')
```

My (obviously incorrect) Logic behind query above: 
I wanted to create a table including all the movies starred in by Sidney Crowe `(actor_id = 105)` and their film ID. These films will now be tested one by one: for the films starred in by Sidney Crowe to be part of the result, the not exists clause for this film must be true (which means the list after the not exists must remain empty)

In the second part of the subquery in the `where` clause, the above (Films that Sidney crow starred in) is then tested one by one against the films that Salma Nolte (actor_id = 122) is in.

My result is incorrect and I'm wondering where I messed up or if someone could explain the logic to me that would be amazing thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` twice:

```
select f.*
from Film f 
where 
  exists (
    select 1 from Film_Actor 
    where film_id = f.film_id and actor_id = 105
  )
  and
  exists (
    select 1 from Film_Actor 
    where film_id = f.film_id and actor_id = 122
  )
order by f.title
```

or by grouping first the Film_Actor table and then join to the Film table:

```
select f.* from Film f inner join ( 
  select film_id 
  from Film_Actor
  where actor_id in (105, 122)
  group by film_id
  having count(actor_id) = 2
) g on g.film_id = f.film_id
order by f.title
```

Comment: Could you explain what the "select 1 from Film_Actor" does? Is it select one film? Thank you so much!

Comment: Exists returns true if there exists at least 1 row that satisfies the condition say `film_id = f.film_id and actor_id = 105`. select 1 has no special meaning it could be select * or select 0. The only thing that matters is that the query after exists returms at least 1 row.